# SEO H2 tag placed above H1, does it matter?

Tags: seo, html-heading

I have a site and when you look at the source I have:

```
<h2>Some slogan here</h2>
<h1>Main title</h1>
<h2>Some title goes here</h2>
<h3>Some other title here</h3>
```

My question is, does it matter for SEO the  is placed above the  tag?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I'm not aware you can't "talk" about SEO here on stackoverflow. Guess I need to read the rules again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not matter. It is natural in some circumstances for the `<hx>` tag to come before the `<h1>` in the source code. CSS and JavaScript can change how its position on the screen.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter that much for rankings, but when having allot of messy code in your source it can be a problem